# Is it possible to have different user permissions (who is allowed an who is not) into folders of an svn repo in MacOS X?

Tags: svn, macos, .htpasswd, user-permissions

I have multiple developers working in different projects in the same svn repository, I dont want them to have access to the wrong project.

I thought that having multiple repositories could do the trick, now I dont really know and after trying to find in the web still havent found how or if it is possible to configure svn/apache to allow only a specific account to have access to a specific repository.

Is there any way to achieve this basic level of security with subversion on a Mac OS X?

Is there any way to use htpassword for this?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely do that. Read [this section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir) of the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way would be to make users for each of the SVN users, add them each to the svn group then present access via svn+ssh://user@somehost/path/to/repos.  This gives them an access to a shell, which may be undesirable, this fear can be ameliorated with some sort of chroot jail, which generally requires recompiling openSSH.

another option would be to use webdav with http auth (not secure unless using ssl).